# High water pressure on middle setting on faucet

Tags: bathroom, faucet, water-pressure

I’m in a newly renovated apartment with brand new faucets.

The faucets in both bathrooms (different models) both have a super high pressure, so much so that it makes a mess when you turn them on from the ricochet of the water off your hands.

The shower faucets are fine and the pressure isn’t too high there.

I tried to adjust the shutoff valves for the sink faucets to reduce the pressure.

This improves the problem but introduces a new one. If I adjust the hot and cold pressure to the correct amount then the middle setting on the pressure is too powerful. If I adjust it so the middle setting is the correct amount of pressure then full hot or full cold is too weak.

Is there a way I can have a consistent amount of pressure no matter where the tap is set?

Here’s a video of it in action:
https://www.loom.com/share/af3d65c9bedf444c8ade3cdf656fac6b

Comment: "Apartment" indicates rental. Sounds like it's time to call in the management. Show them the video and have them get the plumbers out to fix the issue. Yes, simply turning a valve to adjust the pressure should be something you're allowed to do, but if doing so doesn't fix the problem, then it's on them to get it worked out.

Comment: @FreeMan- it’s not a rental, it’s my apartment that I bought and had renovated by a contractor. Generally they did a poor job so I’m trying to understand if this is normal or not for the pressure to be weird like this.

Comment: Fair enough. Usually, in the US, the term for that is "condo", so that threw me off.

Comment: You need to be able to adjust the pressure further back, at the main inlet, otherwise you're always going to see the same issue, 1+0=1 either end of the mic balance vs 1+1=2 in the centre.

Comment: **mix** balance, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having a pressure reducer installed at the main inlet to your apartment if that is possible (might not be if there's no access to the feed just to your apartment vs. the other units).  This is basically an adjustable diaphragm which limits the pressure on the output side.

My guess is that the shower valve or the head itself has a flow or pressure limiter which is why the high pressure not as obvious there. Shower heads are often flow limited to save water. Kitchen sinks are often flow limited as well, but generally bathroom sinks and other sinks are not flow limited.